# Elantech touchpad recognized as PS/2 mouse Ubuntu 13.10

Tags: ubuntu, touchpad

My Elantech touchpad won't work correctly in Ubuntu 13.10 (I had the same problem with 13.04).
I can move the cursor and left/right click, but the sensitivity is too high, no scrolling, and no multitouch.

Under System Settings / Mouse & Touchpad, I have no touchpad tab.

This is the result of `xinput --list`

```
   ⎡ Virtual core pointer                       id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
   ⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                 id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
   ⎜   ↳ PS/2 Elantech Touchpad                     id=11   [slave  pointer  (2)]
   ⎜   ↳ ELAN Touchscreen                           id=13   [slave  pointer  (2)]
   ⎣ Virtual core keyboard                      id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
     ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard              id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
     ↳ Power Button                             id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
     ↳ Video Bus                                id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
     ↳ Power Button                             id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
     ↳ Sleep Button                             id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
     ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard             id=10   [slave  keyboard (3)]
     ↳ Integrated Camera                        id=12   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

I have tried updating the kernel and installing either psmouse-elantech-v6 and psmouse-elantech-v7 drivers, but nothing helped.

What else could I try? Thanks

Answer (score 5):

You probably have a laptop with a newer version of the Elan touchpad.

Check out comment #137 on this thread - download the dkms package and follow the instructions to see if that helps.

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1166442/+index?comments=all

Note that this doesn't seem to work for some Gigabyte notebooks.

[Edit] As requested, the solution from the link above is:

Step 1: Download the following dkms package

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1166442/+attachment/3941591/+files/psmouse-elantech-x551c.tar.gz

Step 2: Run the following commands in the download directory (or adjust the paths accordingly):

```
sudo dkms ldtarball psmouse-elantech-x551c.tar.gz
sudo dkms install -m psmouse -v elantech-x551c
sudo rmmod psmouse
sudo modprobe psmouse
```

Comment: It would be helpful to copy the solution here and provide the link for reference in case the link goes dead in future

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I tried that solution, but it made no difference.

Comment: @Maiagallo - sorry to hear that. You might want to post your HW info on the open bug for the subset of users for which the fix doesn't work. https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1272777

Answer (score 0):

The new kernel ubuntu 3.18 multitouch enabled my ETPS / 2 Elantech Touchpad with zoom photos, vertical and horizontal scrolling with two fingers like in windows 8.1. Tested on ubuntu 14.10 with all updates.

Comment: In my case I have 3.19rc7 but no luck :(