# Asus Vivobook S551LN trackpad doesn't work with Linux Mint 17

Tags: linux-mint, touchpad

I've just received my new ASUS laptop and installed Linux Mint on it right away.
Everything works so far, except for the trackpad: it <strike>only moves a few millimetres every few seconds.</strike> doesn't receive any input at all.

The laptop has a touchscreen which works fine.

Here is the output of `xinput list`:

```
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ USBest Technology SiS HID Touch Controller    id=11   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ PS/2 Logitech Wheel Mouse                 id=14   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Sleep Button                              id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ USB2.0 UVC HD Webcam                      id=10   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Asus WMI hotkeys                          id=12   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=13   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

If there is anything else you need to know, please let me know.

EDIT:

I've been following instructions at https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DebuggingTouchpadDetection.
These are my findings:

An external mouse works.

`cat /proc/bus/input/devices` output:

```
I: Bus=0019 Vendor=0000 Product=0005 Version=0000
N: Name="Lid Switch"
P: Phys=PNP0C0D/button/input0
S: Sysfs=/devices/LNXSYSTM:00/device:00/PNP0C0D:00/input/input0
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=event0 
B: PROP=0
B: EV=21
B: SW=1

I: Bus=0019 Vendor=0000 Product=0003 Version=0000
N: Name="Sleep Button"
P: Phys=PNP0C0E/button/input0
S: Sysfs=/devices/LNXSYSTM:00/device:00/PNP0C0E:00/input/input1
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=kbd event1 
B: PROP=0
B: EV=3
B: KEY=4000 0 0 0 0

I: Bus=0019 Vendor=0000 Product=0001 Version=0000
N: Name="Power Button"
P: Phys=LNXPWRBN/button/input0
S: Sysfs=/devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXPWRBN:00/input/input2
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=kbd event2 
B: PROP=0
B: EV=3
B: KEY=100000 0 0 0

I: Bus=0011 Vendor=0001 Product=0001 Version=ab41
N: Name="AT Translated Set 2 keyboard"
P: Phys=isa0060/serio0/input0
S: Sysfs=/devices/platform/i8042/serio0/input/input3
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=sysrq kbd event3 
B: PROP=0
B: EV=120013
B: KEY=4 2000000 3803078 f800d001 feffffdf ffefffff ffffffff fffffffe
B: MSC=10
B: LED=7

I: Bus=0003 Vendor=093a Product=2510 Version=0111
N: Name="PixArt USB Optical Mouse"
P: Phys=usb-0000:00:14.0-1/input0
S: Sysfs=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb2/2-1/2-1:1.0/input/input8
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=mouse0 event4 
B: PROP=0
B: EV=17
B: KEY=70000 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
B: REL=103
B: MSC=10

I: Bus=0019 Vendor=0000 Product=0006 Version=0000
N: Name="Video Bus"
P: Phys=LNXVIDEO/video/input0
S: Sysfs=/devices/LNXSYSTM:00/device:00/PNP0A08:00/device:06/LNXVIDEO:00/input/input9
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=kbd event5 
B: PROP=0
B: EV=3
B: KEY=3e000b 0 0 0 0 0 0 0

I: Bus=0019 Vendor=0000 Product=0006 Version=0000
N: Name="Video Bus"
P: Phys=LNXVIDEO/video/input0
S: Sysfs=/devices/LNXSYSTM:00/device:00/PNP0A08:00/LNXVIDEO:01/input/input10
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=kbd event6 
B: PROP=0
B: EV=3
B: KEY=3e000b 0 0 0 0 0 0 0

I: Bus=0000 Vendor=0000 Product=0000 Version=0000
N: Name="HDA Intel PCH Headphone"
P: Phys=ALSA
S: Sysfs=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1b.0/sound/card1/input15
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=event7 
B: PROP=0
B: EV=21
B: SW=4

I: Bus=0000 Vendor=0000 Product=0000 Version=0000
N: Name="HDA Intel PCH Mic"
P: Phys=ALSA
S: Sysfs=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1b.0/sound/card1/input14
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=event8 
B: PROP=0
B: EV=21
B: SW=10

I: Bus=0000 Vendor=0000 Product=0000 Version=0000
N: Name="HDA Intel HDMI HDMI/DP,pcm=8"
P: Phys=ALSA
S: Sysfs=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:03.0/sound/card0/input18
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=event9 
B: PROP=0
B: EV=21
B: SW=140

I: Bus=0000 Vendor=0000 Product=0000 Version=0000
N: Name="HDA Intel HDMI HDMI/DP,pcm=7"
P: Phys=ALSA
S: Sysfs=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:03.0/sound/card0/input17
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=event10 
B: PROP=0
B: EV=21
B: SW=140

I: Bus=0000 Vendor=0000 Product=0000 Version=0000
N: Name="HDA Intel HDMI HDMI/DP,pcm=3"
P: Phys=ALSA
S: Sysfs=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:03.0/sound/card0/input16
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=event11 
B: PROP=0
B: EV=21
B: SW=140

I: Bus=0003 Vendor=0457 Product=1024 Version=0111
N: Name="USBest Technology SiS HID Touch Controller"
P: Phys=usb-0000:00:14.0-7/input0
S: Sysfs=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb2/2-7/2-7:1.0/input/input20
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=mouse1 event12 
B: PROP=2
B: EV=b
B: KEY=400 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
B: ABS=2608000 3

I: Bus=0003 Vendor=13d3 Product=5195 Version=0718
N: Name="USB2.0 UVC HD Webcam"
P: Phys=usb-0000:00:14.0-5/button
S: Sysfs=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb2/2-5/2-5:1.0/input/input22
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=kbd event13 
B: PROP=0
B: EV=3
B: KEY=100000 0 0 0 0 0 0

I: Bus=0019 Vendor=0000 Product=0000 Version=0000
N: Name="Asus WMI hotkeys"
P: Phys=asus-nb-wmi/input0
S: Sysfs=/devices/platform/asus-nb-wmi/input/input23
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=rfkill kbd event14 
B: PROP=0
B: EV=100013
B: KEY=80000 0 0 8000 0 0 0 0 0 a1606f 900000 82000278 501000 e0000 0 0 0
B: MSC=10

I: Bus=0011 Vendor=0002 Product=0001 Version=0063
N: Name="PS/2 Logitech Wheel Mouse"
P: Phys=isa0060/serio4/input0
S: Sysfs=/devices/platform/i8042/serio4/input/input19
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=mouse2 event15 
B: PROP=0
B: EV=7
B: KEY=70000 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
B: REL=3
```

It does not contain the Synaptics driver that it ought to, does this mean this is a legit linux kernel bug, as the page states? Any other ideas?

Comment: Did you try `sudo modprobe -r psmouse` and `sudo modprobe psmouse proto=imps`? It seems it fixed previous bugs with mint.

Comment: Tried just now, didn't work.

Comment: Which version of Mint? Are there Ubuntu drivers for the touchpad? Does a normal USB mouse work? Your question says PS/2 rather than USB. However, many touchpads appear as PS/2

Comment: Check the EDIT 2 of smssms in [this post](http://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?f=49&t=114085). With the steps of the following post of  hugo_koopmans (stop x server, create a xorg.conf.new...)

Comment: @Big Chris 17. haven't found any online. Yes, as i state in the question.

Comment: @Hastur It seems that your suggestion did solve something: Things are always clickable again. I wouldn't be able to click some icons or windows in some situations before, now i can, so that's one fix.

Comment: MATE or Cinnamon? Have a look in Synaptic Package Manager for "touchpad"... There might be some clues or additional installs to try...

Comment: If installed with `synclient -l` you should have an overview about the Synaptics' driver options with typical value as ...MinSpeed = 1, MaxSpeed = 1.75,  AccelFactor = 0.0373065 ... And the possibility to modify them.

Comment: `Couldn't find synaptics properties. No synaptics driver loaded?`

Comment: I use Cinnamon.

Comment: In [another post](http://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?f=49&t=111647) they suggest that similar problems can arise from wrong options in the `options.conf`, and propose to fix it or to use a workaround as  the full path for the kernel module loading... maybe an hint.

Comment: Have a look at this Linux Mint [article](http://community.linuxmint.com/tutorial/view/1361).

Comment: Check out [this][1]. It helped me when I was on Mint

  [1]: http://superuser.com/questions/721417/elantech-touchpad-recognized-as-ps-2-mouse-ubuntu-13-10