# Weird mouse issue with browsers Arch Linux

Tags: linux, browser, mouse, arch-linux, touchpad

When I'm browsing my touchpad two finger scroll is "laggy". 
If I plug a usb mouse, the wheel scroll does not work.
It happens with Goole Chrome (from AUR), Chromium and Firefox.

Everywhere else in the system wheels/touchpad scroll work fine.

Anyone experiencing this? Is there a way to fix this?

I'm running Arch Linux on a ASUS laptop (PU301L) with Gnome Shell 3.12.2.
I had to follow [this](https://superuser.com/questions/721417/elantech-touchpad-recognized-as-ps-2-mouse-ubuntu-13-10) in order to let the system correctly recognize my touchpad

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After searching around I gave up. Now I'm on manjaro linux and my touchpad works fine, so I'm sure I've been missing something in the way

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure you followed instructions at [archilinux GDM wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/GDM). I've had your problem and it seems the line

```
xmodmap -e "pointer =1 2 3 6 7 4 5" # set mouse buttons up correctly
```

in **~/.xprofile** file was causing the problem. I commented that line and restarted and everything was fine again.